# Where to add a function

Tags: c#

I am working on a challenge on coding games. While the following code won't solve the problem and I am no looking for the answer.

The problem I have is that I am trying to create a function called Train() however I get the error `CS1525: Unexpected symbol public`.

I have placed the function before and after the while loop and right after the main function.

```
class Player
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {               

        while (true)
        {          

            Train();
        }

        public void  Train()
        {
            if (gold >= 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TRAIN 1 1 0");
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting the code to run and use the Train() to write TRAIN 1 1 0 to the screen instead I get the error `CS1525: Unexpected symbol public`.

Comment: Hi it looks like you have a typo - declare `Train` in the body of the class not in the `Main` function.

Comment: @jspcal Starting with C# 7.0, C# [supports local functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions). However these are private to the method in which they are declared. They cannot be public.

Comment: If you are using a more current version of C#, you could remove the `public` from that definition of the `Train()` function and it would work as well, since could may define local functions. But whether or not you would want to do that would depend on what the rest of your code looks like and what you hope to do with the function.

Comment: Hi it looks like you have a typo - declare Train in the body of the class not in the Main function

If I create the function before main I get the error "CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `Player.Train()" related to the line inside the while loop. I guess that mean it can't access the function from outside Main.

I don't know what version of C# it is.  It's a web-based version on codingame.com

Removing public I get the error CS1547: Keyword `void' cannot be used in this context.

Comment: Train() was called but I screwed up when writing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not define the method within the main method.

```
class Player
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {          
        while (true)
        {      
            Move();
        }
    }

    public void  Train()
    {
        if (gold >= 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TRAIN 1 1 0");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you call Train to an instance of Player you can call it. If you call it without an instance, make the method static like main is.

Comment: That worked, it caused another problem but I want to spend some time trying to figure that out.  Thank you.